# Sentence ending with 先

Tags: grammar

> 渋谷駅近くにある大型書店。ハチ公口から出てすぐ、観光客やユーチューバーが三脚や自撮り棒といった思い思いの方法で撮影している風景を横目にスクランブル交差点を渡った**先**。

The narrator seems to walk across Shibuya Crossing after leaving Hachikou's entrance. But I don't get what 先 is doing at the end of this sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ～を渡った先。

It's a contracted way of saying 渡った先だ/です。

I think here it means (それは)～を渡った先だ/です。or 先にある/あります。
The omitted subject is the 大型書店.

The [先]{さき} means:

> さき【先】〘名〙
> ❸ ある基準より空間的に前の方。前方。
> 「目的地を目指して先へ進む」「技術では一歩先を行く」「銀行とデパートは目と鼻の先（＝すぐ近く）にある」「玄関先」
> (明鏡国語辞典)

> （その書店は、）スクランブル交差点を渡った先（です/にあります）。
> You'll see the bookstore after you've walked across Shibuya Crossing.